# Error when starting MySQL

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I installed MySQL with homebrew. When I run `mysql.server start` I get the following error:

```
ERROR!The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql...
local.pid
```

I have searched this site and googled this and I do what it tells me to do but I've had no luck.

Comment: Instead of any init.d script, start `mysqld` in the foreground without forking, and it will probably tell you why it fails.

Comment: Ok, I get the following error and I don't know how to fix it:  ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: `mysqld` NOT `mysql` .... In other words: start an unforked mysql instance with stdout & stderr to your console.

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried so far? Did you run the following after installation:

```
brew info mysql
```

If you did, it might be a problem with permissions. You might need to give the user permission to write to the PID file.

Comment: How do I exactly do that? I did sudo chown -R [user name] PID. This is probably wrong because I work with the hardware side of the computer not the software part until now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for that - `brew info mysql` gives some useful info.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can use `mysql_install_db` to install your MySQL system tables. Then you can use `mysql.server start`.